# Reset Macro OnKey-Assignment to Default does not work for Recorded Macros

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2016, a few days ago, by mistake I assigned a macro to Ctrl+y in the Macro-Recorder window.

Now, I would like to reset Ctrl+y to its default behaviour.

For this I found the following code:

```
Sub keys_deleteHotKeys()
   ' https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/keyboard-shortcut-run-macro/
    Application.OnKey "^y", ""
    Call Application.OnKey("^y")
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the above Sub has no effect.

Does excel follow a different way of handling macro to key assignments when done in the Macro Recorder window as compared to a VBA `Application.OnKey` assignment?

Comment: So did you already remove the shortcut to the macro?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the macro list menu available from your Developer Ribbon tab, select your corresponding macro, then `Option...` and delete the shortcut you set.

Answer (score 0):

The macro recorder always includes a hidden member attribute for the assigned hotkey, and there's nothing in the IDE to modify or otherwise manipulate it. You could export the code file, edit it (remove the hidden `Attribute` line), and re-import it into your VBA project... but that's quite a pain in the neck.

Get [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (free, open-source VBIDE add-in project that I manage), and then you can do this:

```
'@ExcelHotkey("y")
Public Sub MyAwesomeMacro()
    'do stuff...
End Sub
```

That annotation/comment can then be turned into the very same hidden member attribute Excel uses when you record macros and assign a hotkey (via static code analysis; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58600561/1188513) for all the details).

The lowecase "y" is what makes the hotkey Ctrl+y. If you want the hotkey to be Ctrl+Shift+y, simply make it a capital "Y":

```
'@ExcelHotkey("Y")
Public Sub MyAwesomeMacro()
    'do stuff...
End Sub
```

The advantages of this approach are numerous:

- No obscure hidden member attributes to manipulate.
- No need to export/edit/import anything.
- Obscure hidden member attributes are surfaced/documented.
- No need for any `Application.OnKey` hack.
- You get an inspection result whenever attributes & annotations disagree, and you get to synchronize the values with a single click.

If all you want is to remove the hotkey attribute, then simply run code inspections; Rubberduck will tell you when there's a hidden attribute without a corresponding annotation comment, and you can then decide whether to remove the attribute or add a corresponding annotation comment.

---

<sub>Note: the feature will work perfectly fine for OP's needs (*removing* the hidden attribute), but a [regression bug was filed](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/5268), since *adding* the hidden attribute is broken in v2.4.1.5170.</sub>